# Returning same function signature as the received one

Tags: function, generics, typescript

I'm trying to create an interceptor function. In my specific case, a **throttle** function.

Consider the following example:

```
function throttle(func: Function, wait: number = 0): Function {
    let previous: {
        args: any[];
        timestamp: number;
        result: any;
    } = {
        args: [],
        timestamp: 0,
        result: null
    };
    return (...currentArgs: any[]): any => {
        const now = Date.now();
        const remaining = wait && (wait - (now - previous.timestamp));
        const argumentsChanged = JSON.stringify(currentArgs) !== JSON.stringify(previous.args);
        if (argumentsChanged || (wait && (remaining <= 0 ||remaining > wait))) {
            previous = {
                args: currentArgs,
                timestamp: now,
                result: func.apply(this, currentArgs)
            };
        }
        return previous.result;
    };
}
```

This function will initially call the function passed by argument and will not call it again until the specified *wait* time has been reached or the target function's arguments changed.

The problem with this is that it should return the same function type as the function passed in by argument, so it can be transparent to the caller.

For instance, this should be allowed but it's not:

```
function updateStatus(id: number, newStatus: string): void {
  // ...
}

// ...

// Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(id: number, newStatus: string) => void'
this.updateStatus = throttle(this.updateStatus.bind(this), 500);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Function` type use a generic constraint.
The function signature should look like this:

```
function throttle<T extends Function>(func: T, wait: number = 0): T
```

In a simple example:

```
function throttle<T extends Function>(func: T, wait: number = 0): T {
    return null;
}

function fn(a: string, b: number): boolean {
    return false;
}

let throttled = throttle(fn, 3); // type of throttled: (a: string, b: number) => boolean
throttled("stirng", 0); // ok
throttled(3, 4); // error: Argument of type '3' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20throttle%3CT%20extends%20Function%3E(func%3A%20T%2C%20wait%3A%20number%20%3D%200)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fn(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20throttled%20%3D%20throttle(fn%2C%203)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20throttled%3A%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%0D%0Athrottled(%22stirng%22%2C%200)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0Athrottled(3%2C%204)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'3'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'string'%0D%0A))